# Simple example of using Fedora alternatives to install old version of make

Tags: linux, fedora, package-management, alternatives

Can anyone help me using the Fedora alternatives system in order to install an old version of make? I know the actual program is irrelevant, but I need it so I'll use it as my example.

I currently have `make-3.82` installed on my Fedora 14 box, but I need to have 3.81 installed to build the android kernel. I already downloaded the 3.81 source and built it, but now I want to install it alongside 3.82 and be able to switch between them using Fedora alternatives.

Now I installed `make-3.81` from source into `/usr/local`, how would I use alternatives to achieve my goal? I know I must use the alternatives command, but so far my attempts have failed and I would like a concrete example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. You need to 'alternative-ize' the original make.  Change /usr/bin/make and /usr/bin/gmake to /usr/bin/make-3.82 and /usr/bin/gmake-3.82.  Realize that it'll get blown away next time make is upgraded, because Fedora does not use the alternatives for make.
2. Create an alternative for it.  `alternatives --install /usr/bin/make make /usr/bin/make-3.82 10` for make.  I used 10 as the priority to make it a lower priority than the next step.
3. Now create an alternative for your new make. `alternatives --install /usr/bin/make make /usr/local/make-3.81/bin/make 20` (assuming you installed it in /usr/local/make-3.81).  notice I used a higher priority, 20.
4. Use `alternatives --display make` to see what is being used.

Comment: Commenting on my own answer:  the `alternatives` system is probably not the best solution to this problem.  You might benefit from Environment Modules (http://modules.sourceforge.net/), or just manually setting the old make in your PATH or the Makefile.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer! This worked like a charm and cleared up confusion around the alternatives system.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the suggestion. I'll be sure to check that out.

Comment: +1 for "the right answer is don't do this".

Comment: At any rate I think I'll be able to better use alternatives, if I find the right situation. ;)